# JMeter with TFS

Tags: tfs, jmeter

How to integrate my JMeter test (.jmx) files with TFS?

Is there any way to attach/import my entire JMeter test plan with TFS? I coudn't see any of the JMeter plugins that supports TFS.

Please let me know the procedures in it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate it using pure command line tasks as explained in the [Jmeter TFS integration Article](https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/configuring-jmeter-tests-in-vsts-tfs-azure-devops-and-publishing-results-dcdd7b451cb9).

This is basically what you will need:

- An Agent with this capabilities

  - Java 1.8 (works with older versions too)
  - JMeter 5 (same as above, you can use different versions)
- JMeter script you like to execute

The CLI Tasks that you add do 4 basic things:

1. Setup environment variables for JMETER_HOME
2. Run the JMeter script
3. Generate the JMeter report
4. (Optional but recommended) parse de JMeter report as a JUnit report so you can see more detail results in TFS. You can use [this script](https://github.com/egoetschalckx/jmeter2nunit) if you want your results reported as C# NUint instead

Answer (score -1):

You can store anything in TFS: source code, photos of kitten, video from your wedding, etc.

So you can import your JMeter script using [TFS Add command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-command?view=azure-devops)

```
tf add your_script.jmx
```

If you want to go further and automate JMeter script execution - you should not be looking for JMeter plugin for TFS, but rather for JMeter plugin for the [Continuous Integration Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jenkins-vs-other-open-source-continuous-integration-servers). Given the nature of your question my guess is that this is [Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/get-started-jmeter-test?view=azure-devops) or similar.